# How to get list of files alphanumerically greater than text specified in Linux command line (bash) via ftp connection?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, ftp

I have new job and instead of designing and solving complicated problems in C++ architecture on Windows, I have to finish issues using bash scripts on Linux. I forgot bash commands and haven't ever written any .sh script. So now I have environment running and I am connected to remote folder via ftp. 
My simple problem is following: 
There are files like batch_something20160818012830, batch_something20160818012925, batch_something20160818013100, .. and the end of the filename is date time, for example batch_something20160818012830 has date 8.18.2016 and time 1:28:30, all of the filenames have same length and I need to get all the filenames alpanumerically larger then some datetime, for example I want larger than 8.18.2016 1:29:30, so I create text batch_something20160818012930 and I want to compare this text with filenames and get filenames greater than it, so batch_something20160818012925 and batch_something20160818013100 from the 3 above, how to do it? 
I need it to be working via ftp, so I found commands ls and dir and there will be a lot of the files so if it's possible, then I want to receive only the final file names without sending the list of all files inside the remote folder.

Maybe ls/dir --ignore=PATTERN or somehow use ls/dir with regex?

EDIT: I am already connected via ftp -i localhost and the amount of files can be big, so I think that using pipes to send some semi-results between commands is not good and I would prefer to use 1 command does the work on it's own.

Comment: You can't connect via SSH?

Comment: I think I can't, either ftp or sftp.

Answer (score 0):

```
lftp "-e cls -1 --sort name; quit" ftp://ftp.kernel.org:/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x|sed -n '/patch-4.5.xz/,$p'
```

Use `lftp` to logint to ftp, get a list in alphabetically order (`--sort`), quit; then piping it to sed which cuts the heading lines before the match `patch-4.5.xz`, so you get the alphabetically larger files list on stdout.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of some kind to your answer? There is no telling what that line of code does.

Comment: Ok, something like that is obvious solution (but I wasn't sure about the syntax anyway), but I already used ftp and I probably shouldn't use another program (lftp). 
The problem is that I want to filter the file names using 1 program so the file names don't get send via pipe to another program, because the amount of file names will be big.

Comment: That's pity that you shouldn't use pipes. Then use any higher level language than shell (e.g. python, perl), because shell is heavily based on pipes.